# How do I speed up or Improve this query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following structure:

```sql
id    widget_id    value    date_recorded
-----------------------------------------------
1         1          10     2019-10-12 12:00:15
2         2          15     2019-10-12 12:00:15
3         3          20     2019-10-12 12:00:15
4         4          50     2019-10-12 12:00:15 
5         1          12     2019-10-15 00:05:15
6         2          19     2019-10-15 00:05:15
7         3          25     2019-10-15 00:05:15
8         4          75     2019-10-15 00:05:15
```

This table has roughly 500,000 records as we need to keep historic data of the widget values. There are about three hundred different unique widget id's, and an equal amount of records for each id, so figure just shy of 1700 records per id.

Most of the time we simply need to grab the most up to date value for a given Id or for all ids, but I am finding that the query takes longer than expected, especially when looping through all needed ids.

I have tried the following two queries:

This first one takes between three hundred and five hundred MS. Over three hundred records that adds up.

```sql
SELECT 
  widget_id,
  value,
  date_recorded
  FROM widget_values
  WHERE  widget_id = 1
  ORDER BY date_recorded DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

This one takes 500 ms or longer

```sql
SELECT 
  widget_id,
  value,
  date_recorded
  FROM widget_values
  WHERE widget_id = 1
  AND date_recorded = (
      SELECT 
      MAX(date_recorded)
      FROM widget_values
      WHERE widget_id = 1
      )
```

I am wondering the following:

1. Is there any way to perform these operations faster or perhaps to get the most recent values for all unique id's in one query?
2. Being that this data set will double in size every few months, is a better strategy to store the most recent values for pertinent id's in a separate table so it is a less intense operation to grab them? So I would have one table storing historic values and another that always holds just the 300 most recent values. This feels like some kind of design violation but also seems like a fair solution to a growing problem.

```sql
| widget_values | CREATE TABLE `widget_values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `widget_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_recorded` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `widget_id` (`widget_id`),
  KEY `value` (`value`),
  KEY `date_recorded` (`date_recorded`),
  CONSTRAINT `widget_amounts_one` FOREIGN KEY (`widget_id`) REFERENCES `widget_codes` (`widget_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: just to make sure we've covered all bases: assuming you've created an index on the necessary columns?

Comment: @Jhecht I have a primary auto increment key on id and have an index on widget_id and value.

Comment: can you add `show create table widget_values`

Comment: Order by, is going to make MySql go through each record to sort the columns.

Comment: Can you please try this for the second one? In the second query the subquery is going to get executed each time. What I have done is to create one temporary table that is going to get executed for once only.

SELECT 
  widget_id,
  value,
  date_recorded
  FROM widget_values
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT 
    MAX(date_recorded)
      FROM widget_values
      WHERE widget_id = 1
  )
  AS maxed_record ON maxed_record.date_recorded = widget_values.date_recorded

Comment: @EchoMike444 - show create table added.

Comment: @ATULKUMARSINGH getting 'Unknown column 'maxed_record.date_recorded' in 'on clause'

Comment: Sorry missed the aliasing in the query. Please try this: SELECT widget_id, value, date_recorded
FROM widget_values
INNER JOIN (
SELECT MAX(date_recorded) as date_recorded
FROM widget_values
WHERE widget_id = 1) AS maxed_record ON maxed_record.date_recorded = widget_values.date_recorded

Answer (score 1):

What's the meaning of column `date_recorded`? If it's just the data's create time, you can use the column `id` to sort:

```sql
SELECT 
  widget_id,
  value,
  date_recorded
  FROM widget_values
  WHERE  widget_id = 1
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

This will hit the primary key index.

Comment: This is a excellent point and while I thought the date was a necessary evil in this, you are correct in that the most recent ID per the widget id would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

A multi-column index on `( widget_id , date_recorded )` will help you .

The main drawback of having to many indexes is you have a penalty for each insert,update,delete .

When you want to optimize access to a table , you must verify each different query against the table and see if you have the right index .

A possible optimization is to remove the column `id` , and turn `widget_id , date_recorded` to a `primary key` . So you will have only one index . This optimization can not be pertinent , if others tables need reference  a single row  , because the you will use more bytes to store a reference `widget_id , date_recorded`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from having index on your table, You may try below query to improve performance -

```
SELECT 
  widget_id,
  value,
  date_recorded
FROM widget_values
WHERE widget_id = 1
ORDER BY date_recorded DESC
LIMIT 1;
```